# Apple id not logging in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, vmware

In my windows system, I have `iOS` set up through VM ware, I have apple id, when I try to sign in using my apple id, it is not giving any response. I found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233193/appleid-not-been-accepted-in-xcode-account-pane) .  So, in order to sign in in Xcode, do I need to pay for membership, without this can't I sign in?

Please help, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can add apple id through add account but for provisioning certificate & device registration you need to purchase apple developer membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to login using my apple id. I got update from app store so i have updated the software(Now version is OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6 ). Now i am able to login. Hope this will help to others

Answer (score 1):

Try after few hours, maybe apple server issue.

Try a restart a system and try again too.

I get these types of issues sometimes. hope it will work fine soon.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i am facing this issue from long time, i have tried so many times from past one month. Still bad luck...

Comment: Restarted my machine. That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sign in to xcode you don't need to register with apple developer membership!  You can simply create an Apple ID and sign in to xcode, from `Preferences - accounts`. You need an Apple developer membership when you want to submit an app to the App Store or when you want to test a feature like push notifications.

Sometimes it happens that you can't add a new account in xcode and therefore can't sign in because of an issue with Apple's servers.

But as you mentioned that you are using `Mac in VMWare` that might be also the issue. If MacOS found out that it was running in an emulator then it is possible that it would not allow you to sign in. Try after a few hours, if you can sign in then it was a problem with the server!

Comment: Thank you for reply, i have done preference - accounts this. If i give wrong credentials it saying apple id or password is incorrect, but i give correct details it is showing progress..Finally i have to force quit the X Code. I dont know why it is not sign in.